# Run a GET request to directory using create-react-app

Tags: php, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm creating a login function on a create-react-app project, but I'm not sure how the directory structure of the build file works... When running the request I receive a 404 error.

I have a function in `createUser.js`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get("./RestAPI/UserCRUD/create.php", function(users) {
        this.setState({
            users: users.records
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

which would ideally run the php script I've written that accesses the database. My question how do I find the URL I need to specify on the get request to call this file on the `build` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `RestAPI` is your php project directory name

So if you want to call rest api from reactjs you should declare full url of the rest api like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get("http://localhost/RestAPI/UserCRUD/create.php", function(users) {
        this.setState({
            users: users.records
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Hope it helps!!